# Jboss 5.1 GA doesn't recognize @font-face files as resources, error 403

Tags: css, jsf-2, font-face, jboss5.x

I'm trying to use Open Sans font family on Jboss 5.1 GA but it returns "Resource 'META-INF/css/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.woff' is not supported". The same goes for ttf and svg files.

In other JSF projects running on different environments I declared my fonts like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'OpenSansRegular';
src: url("#{resource['fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot']}");
src: url("#{resource['fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot']}?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
url("#{resource['fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff']}") format('woff'),
url("#{resource['fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf']}") format('truetype'),
url("#{resource['fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg']}#OpenSansRegular") format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

And the Mime type on web.xml:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>otf</extension>
    <mime-type>font/opentype</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>ttf</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-font-ttf</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>woff</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-font-woff</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>eot</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-font-eot</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

I never had any issue with @font-face and Jboss before, even with IE. I am able to access other resources like JS and images by their absolute path but when I try to browse the font files, it returns 403:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) http://localhost:8080/project/resource/css/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.woff
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) http://localhost:8080/project/resource/css/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.ttf
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) http://localhost:8080/project/resource/css/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.svg#OpenSansSemiBold
```

Is there any restriction with Jboss 5.1?